# MopaBootstrapBundle Installation,which file put these bundle setting code

Tags: symfony, bundle

***I flowed this [installation](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/v2.0.x/README.md) doc***

[image] 
***which file should i put above code?***

***my project demo is [symfony2 demo](https://github.com/jnuc093/sym)***

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, because your question's detail is now Out of date. But for the general question "How to install MopaBootstrapBundle" please go to https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Answer (score 1):

You are using Symfony 2.2, so use composer to add bundles to your project:
Edit `composer.json` in your project and add the following line under the require section:

```
"mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
```

(See the [current documentation](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-installation.md))

---

### Important

You **don't need** to have the `vendor` folder in your git repository (same goes for the `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders).
Be careful when you push your `parameter.yml` because your repository being public, everyone can access those information.

Consider adding the following lines in your `.gitignore` file

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

and read carefully: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html